# Appropriate way to run a block of code in Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I can't seem to find a proof of running a block of shell code in Chef. For example, I have a script below:

```
for user in `awk -F: '($3 < 500) {print $1 }' /etc/passwd` ; do
    if [ $user != "root" ]; then
      usermod -L $user 
      if [ $user != "sync" ] && [ $user != "shutdown" ] && [ $user != "halt" ];
then 
        usermod -s /sbin/nologin $user
        fi
      fi
done
```

..and I doubt the way to run this block is as follows

```
bash 'run script' do
  code <<-EOH
        "for user in `awk -F: '($3 < 500) {print $1 }' /etc/passwd` ; do
            if [ $user != "root" ]; then
            usermod -L $user
            if [ $user != "sync" ] && [ $user != "shutdown" ] && [ $user != "halt" ];
        then
                usermod -s /sbin/nologin $user
            fi
        fi
    done"
 EOH
end
```

But I'm really unsure if this construct is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the extra `""` on the outside, `<<-EOH ... EOH` is already a kind of quote, called a heredoc.

Comment: So the block inside <<-EOH ... EOH run at once right?

Comment: It's run when the resource converges, yes.

Comment: Is running multiple commands similar to this one from construct perspective? e.g I'd just need to put each comment per line, and still have them wrapped in heredoc.

Comment: So this is not a normal way to use Chef, the bash (and similar) resources are useful for edge cases, but you should, eventually, rewrite all this base code into Chef recipe code using Chef resources. But in general, sure, the whole string you pass in as `code` is handed to Bash and Bash runs it for you.